# Does the existence of a recursive sequence that involves an arbitrary choice at every step require the axiom of choice?

Tags: axiom-of-choice, recursion

Say I want to define a sequence $(x_n)$ recursively, and at each step I make an arbitrary selection for $x_{n+1}$ out of some nonempty pool of acceptable candidates dependent on $x_n$. Does the existence of this sequence rest on the axiom of choice (or perhaps a weaker form)? And if so, how? That is, what would be the nonempty sets from which I choose each $x_n$?

Comment: I'm _pretty_ sure that this doesn't, that iterative selections can be done without the axiom of choice.   You only need the axiom of choice to make a bunch of simultaneous selections.   That's how it was explained to me, anyways...but I'm not taking set theory until next semester

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice

Comment: You need something at least as strong as countable choice (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice) because you can take the acceptable candidates for $x_n$ to be the elements of some arbitrary sequence of nonempty sets $S_n$. But dependent choice is known to be strictly stronger.

Comment: But then the $S_n$ are recursively constructed themselves!

Comment: I was at the wikipedia page for dependent choice a few hours ago, but I've had trouble seeing how it applies to recursive sequences. There is that bit near the middle about how it is required for transfinite recursions of countable length, but I don't think I want that sort of machinery in this case.

Answer (score 6):

In general, this (whenever we define by recursion a sequence, then it exists) is equivalent to the principle of dependent choice. Which we will formulate here in the following way:

> If $X$ is a non-empty set, and $R$ is a binary relation on $X$, such that for every $x\in X$ there is some $y\in X$ such that $x\mathrel R y$, then there is a function $f\colon\Bbb N\to X$ such that $f(n)\mathrel R f(n+1)$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

To see the equivalence, first note that this implies the principle of dependent choice. If our principle holds, and $X$ is a non-empty set, $R$ is a binary relation satisfying the conditions required, then we define by recursion, $x_0$ to be some arbitrary element of $X$, and if $x_n$ was defined, then $x_{n+1}$ is some $y$ such that $x_n\mathrel R y$ is true. By our principle there is a sequence, which is a function $f(n)=x_n$, satisfying the wanted property.

On the other hand, if the principle of dependent choice holds, then our principle holds as well. To see this we need to take a slight detour first. The reason is that (in general) recursive definitions may appeal to previous choices as well, not just the last one that we made.

Suppose that we define a sequence $x_n$, and let $S$ be the set of all possible $x_n$'s, and let $X$ be the set of finite sequences from $S$ which satisfy the property that the sequence obeys our recursive definition. Now consider the relation on $X$, $t\lhd s$ if and only if $t$ is an initial segment of $s$. This relation satisfies the property that every element of $X$ is in the domain of the relation, since the recursion can always continue.

Therefore by the principle of dependent choice there is a function $f\colon\Bbb N\to X$ such that $f(n)\lhd f(n+1)$. But now consider the sequence $x_n=f(n)(n-1)$ (remember that $f(n)$ is a sequence of length at least $n$, so this is well-defined). It is not hard to see that $\{x_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ satisfy the wanted property.

Comment: The second half of your answer is what I was looking for (is there a typo with $x=x_{n+1}$?), but the first half seems interesting too, if only I could make better sense of it!

Comment: Thanks for spotting that typo. If you can tell me what's bugging you about the first half, I could try and make it clearer.

Comment: In the first part of your answer, I'm guessing you're proving that if the kinds of recursive sequences I described do exist, then the principle of dependent choice holds. Are you constructing $f$ so that $f(n)=x_n$, where each $x_{n+1}$ is simply the next term of the sequence guaranteed by hypothesis? I think "induction" is throwing me off a bit.

Comment: Yes, that's what's going on. I'm not constructing $f$, though. I'm proving that the hypothesis of dependent choice hold; then the existence of such $f$ is given by it.

Comment: But, assuming the premises of dependent choice (that $X$ is non-empty, $R$ is a binary relation on $X$, etc.), isn't a construction of $f$ necessary to prove dependent choice?

Comment: But the principle stated in your question (what "this" refers to in the first half of the answer) says that if you define $x_n$ recursively, then the sequence $\{x_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ exists. But the recursion only defines the set of possible $x_{n+1}$ candidates, the existence of a sequence requires a bit more. And that's exactly the non-constructive part.

Comment: In the first part aren't we assuming that such sequences do exist, to show that the principle of dependent choice is a necessary consequence? If we are, then the existence of such sequences is a freebie.

Comment: The statement in your question is this "If you recursively define a sequence, then the sequence exists." And from this statement we can prove the principle of dependent choice; and vice versa.

Comment: Ugh, I found a mistake in the answer (it's true, but the argument needs to be corrected). I'll fix this in a bit.

Comment: Sorry it took so long, but I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Hi. Do you have any reference for this answer or did you find it yourself? Thanks.

Comment: @Math_QED: This is probably in a few books. I think Just and Weese have it in their book. But it's also sufficiently elementary once you understand DC and recursion.

Comment: Thank you. I will check this reference.