# How does Axiom of Dependent Choice imply this weaker variant?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Here is the excerpt from the textbook *A Course in Mathematical Analysis* by Prof D. J. H. Garling.

[image]

So I have the **Theorem 1**:

> Given a set $A\neq\varnothing$, a mapping $\varphi:A\to P(A
> )\setminus \{\varnothing\}$, and $\bar{a}\in A$. Then there exists a sequence
>
> $$(a_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$$
>
> such that $a_{0}=\bar{a}$ and $a_{n+1}\in \varphi(a_{n})$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

**Axiom of Choice**:

> Given a collection $A$ of nonempty sets, there exists a function
>
> $$c: A \to \bigcup_{A_{i} \in A}A_{i}$$
>
> such that $c(A_{i})\in A_{i}$ for all $A_{i} \in A$.

**Axiom of Dependent Choice**:

> Given a nonempty set $A$ and a binary relation $\mathcal{R}$ on $A$ such that for all $a\in A$, there exists $b\in A$ such that $a\mathcal{R}b$. There exists a sequence
>
> $$(a_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$$
>
> such that $a_{n}\mathcal{R}a_{n+1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

The author states that *The axiom of dependent choice
states that this **[Theorem 1]** is always possible*. But I can only infer **Theorem 1** from **Axiom of Choice**, not from **Axiom of Dependent Choice**. Below is how I did it.

> Using Axiom of Choice for the collection $P(A)\setminus \{\varnothing\}$ of nonempty sets, then there exists a choice function $$\varphi':P(A)\setminus \{\varnothing\} \to A$$ such that $\varphi'(X)\in X$ for all $X\in P(A)\setminus \{\varnothing\}$.
>
> Let $\bar{\varphi}=\varphi'\circ \varphi:A\to A\implies\bar{\varphi}(a)=\varphi'(\varphi(a))\in \varphi(\bar{a})$ for all $a\in A$
>
> To sum up, we have $\bar{\varphi}:A\to A$ and $\bar{a}\in A$. Applying Recursion Theorem, we get a sequence $$(a_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$$ such that $a_{0}=\bar{a}$ and $a_{n+1}=\bar{\varphi}(a_{n})\in\varphi(a_{n})$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
>
> So this $(a_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is the required sequence.

I would like you to check my above proof and check whether it is possible for **Axiom of Dependent Choice** to imply **Theorem 1**.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: The answer is a mixture of both: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/963309/does-the-existence-of-a-recursive-sequence-that-involves-an-arbitrary-choice-at and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250623/proof-that-recursive-construction-is-equivalent-to-dependent-choice

Comment: Hi @AsafKaragila, Can you check whether my above proof is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I would think about the problem:

Let $T$ be the set of all finite functions
$$
s \colon n \to A
$$
such that $n \in \mathbb N$, $s(0) = \bar{a}$ and, for all $i +1 < n$,
$$
s(i+1) \in \phi(s(i)).
$$
Let $R \subseteq T \times T$ be given by
$$
R = \{(s,t) \in T^2 \mid t \text{ is a proper end-extension of } s \} = \{ (s,t) \in T^2 \mid s \subsetneq t \}
$$

$R$ satisfies the requirement of DC (since $\phi(a) \neq \emptyset$ for all $a \in A$). Hence there is an infinite sequence (branch) $(s_n \mid n \in \mathbb N)$ through $T$ such that for all $m < n \in \mathbb N \colon s_m \subsetneq s_n$. Let $s := \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} s_n$. For each $k \in \mathbb N$ let $a_k := s(k)$. Then $(a_k \mid n \in \mathbb N)$ is as desired.

Comment: The above also suggest how you can reformulate DC into an equivalent statement that is a generalization of [Kőnig's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_lemma). I find that reformulation much easier to work with in practice. (Mind you: There is a good chance this is only true because I've been inflicted with the 'just build a search tree' virus of inner model theory.)

Comment: To some extent, the tree variant is the clearer version of DC. The reason is that it's easy to translate it into pretty much every other variant.

Comment: I think you meant $s \colon \mathbb N \to A$ rather than $s \colon n \to A$

Comment: @leanhdung No, it's $s \colon n \to A$ -- they are functions with finite domain. (But you should note that, in my notation, $n = \{0,1, \ldots, n-1 \}$ -- that's standard among set theorists but maybe not among other mathematicians.)

Comment: Since $n$ can go to infinity and you wrote "for all $i +1 < n$, $s(i+1) \in\phi(s(i))$", I wonder: did you appeal to  Axiom of choice here to make infinite number of choices?

Comment: @leanhdung At that point I'm not making any choices -- I simply collect all of those sequences into a set (a priori it could be that there just aren't that many such sequences). Then, in a second step, I use DC to show that not only are there infinitely many such sequences -- there is even an infinite 'chain' (a branch) of them. This may not be true in the absence of DC. (Side note: I usually don't take a stance on the 'philosophical truth' of axioms but I must say -- to me DC seems 'true', it's almost mind bending to me to imagine a situation in which it could possibly fail.)

Comment: Now I got that point, but i'm still not sure how *$R$ satisfies the requirement of DC* i.e for all $s\in T$, there exists $s'\in T$ such that $s\subsetneq s'$. Please check my reasoning: 1. Assume $s: n\to A$ such that $s\in T$, let $s': n+1\to A$ such that $s'(x)=s(x)$ for all $x\leqslant n-1$ and $s'(n)\in \phi(s(n-1))\implies s'\in T$ and $s'\subsetneq s$.

Comment: @leanhdung Yep, that works.

Comment: Since I’m just exposed to set theory, I would like to present my complement to your proof to make sure that I understand it correctly. 1. $s$ is a function: Let $(k,a),(k,b) \in g \implies \exists u, v \in (s_n \mid n \in \mathbb N)$ such that $(k,a) \in u, (k,b) \in v$. Assume $u \subsetneq v \implies (k,a) \in v$. Since $(k,a),(k,b) \in v \implies a=b$. Thus $s$ is a function. (cont'd)

Comment: 2. $\mathrm{dom}(s)=\mathbb N$: Since $\forall s \in T, s(0)=a \implies 0 \in \mathrm{dom}(s)$. Assume $n \in \mathrm{dom}(s) \implies \exists s_{t} \in (s_n \mid n \in \mathbb N), n \in \mathrm{dom}(s_{t})$. On the other hand, $s_{t} \subsetneq s_{t+1} \implies n+1 \in \mathrm{dom}(s_{t+1}) \implies n+1 \in \mathrm{dom}(s)$. Thus $\mathrm{dom}(s)=\mathbb N$. (cont'd)

Comment: 3. Condition: Let $(n,a),(n+1,b) \in s \implies \exists s_{t} \in (s_n \mid n \in \mathbb N): (n,a),(n+1,b) \in s_{t}$. Since $s_{t}(n+1) \in \phi(s_{t}(n)), b \in \phi(a)$.

Comment: @DungLe Yep, that works.

Comment: Many thanks for your patience, @StefanMesken. Now I'm done with this question ^_^.

Comment: @DungLe You're welcome!

Comment: I think you meant “for all $m \le n \in \mathbb N \colon s_m \subseteq s_n$” rather than “for all $m \le n \in \mathbb N \colon s_m \subsetneq s_n$” (If $m=n$, then clearly $s_m \subseteq s_n$, not $s_m \subsetneq s_n$). ^_^

Comment: @DungLe I meant for all $m < n \in \mathbb N \colon s_m \subsetneq s_n$. The strict inclusion is important as otherwise the union along a branch could result in a function with finite domain.

Comment: I got it! Could you have a look at my question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2687252/axiom-of-dependent-choice-implies-axiom-of-countable-choice ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal R =\{ (a,b) \in A \times A \mid a,b \in A \text{ and } b \in \phi(a) \}$, then $\mathcal R$ satisfies DC's requirement. Hence there is an infinite sequence (branch) $(a_n \mid n \in \mathbb N)$ through $A$ such that $a_{n+1} \in \phi(a_n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.